# Center vertically within several unknown height div's

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to get this:

[image: Layout]

```
--------------------
Centered Header (Vert+Horizontally) - 15%
--------------------
Centered Image (Vert+Horizontally) - 50%
--------------------
Centered Description (Vert+Horizontally) - 35%
--------------------
```

Each  is a percentage (15%, 50%, 35%) of the total height, which is unknown since I have several different button heights which it needs to work with.

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/x3zq96d5/

I've tried everything I could find online, including the "Centering in the Unknown" page which seemed most suited to what I'm trying.

Each solution has horribly broken things.  What do I need to do to get each of these elements to center within the unknown heights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by utilising the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` CSS rules. See here for an updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x3zq96d5/5/

To make this work, you set `display: table` and `width: 100%` on each of your three divs that have the percentage heights. You then need to add a child div inside them all which has `display: table-cell`, and `vertical-align: middle`. Making this div the only child effectively solely performs a vertical align - then you just need to add your content inside the child div and it will be vertically aligned as you wish.

Disadvantage is that you have to add markup in the form of the child divs which have no semantic meaning, but I think it's a small price to pay and is the neatest way of implementing what you'd like. Also, you need to be careful about your content - in the Fiddle you used h4 and p tags, and these have a default top/bottom margin set by the browser - if this margin is larger than the space available in the percentage height div, it will push the content out of vertical alignment. Fairly obvious but worth noting.

Comment: This did what I needed - it's a bit ugly to add the empty div's but I think the value is worth it here.  Had to make some adjustments to content afterwards based on padding/margin but seem to be on my way. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, in an ideal world the extra divs wouldn't be there. The problem is that newer CSS features like the [flexbox model](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), which go a long way towards solving these sorts of problems properly are only supported in newer browser versions. As always it's a mix of older CSS hacking and newer CSS features.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? On your attached picture, you say all the heights are unknown, but in the jsfiddle, you have declared `.btn` to have a height of 190px.

So, how big do you want the intended parent to be? To make it easy on yourself, you should declare the height of the parent of the elements with the 15%, 50%, and 35% heights. In this case, `.btn` could be either a percentage or fixed value. As a percentage,

```
height:100%
```

Be aware that if you set the height of the `.btn` to 100%, it will inherit its height from its parent—even though it would typically have a height that is defined by the height of its children. When you declare its height as a percentage, it looks to it's parent and becomes a percentage of that. (ie. a div that has a height of 50% will be half as tall as its parent, all else held constant).

If you wanted the height to be 100% of the browser window, you could do

```
html, body, ul, .tall, .btn {
    height:100%;
}
```

Getting the height to be as tall as the browser requires you to declare your height as 100% all the way up to `html`. Or you could just set a fixed height of .btn, which is, well, easier

```
.btn {height:1000px}
```

Now, setting the height of the children elements,

```
btn-modal-header {
  height:15%;
}

.btn-modal-glyph {
  height: 50%;
}

.btn-modal-description {
  height: 35%;
}
```

This will cause them to be a given % of the height of their parent.

As for centering them vertically, you will need to declare a parent with

```
display:table
```

and its child

```
display:table-cell
```

it doesn't have to be a direct child, but it is easier this way. So you could do something like this:

```
.btn > * {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.btn > * > * {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

which sets the children with `15%, 50%, and 35%` heights to `display:table` and their children to be displayed as `table-cell`s. Then, you just have to set their vertical alignment to `middle`.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x3zq96d5/6/

Notice if you resize the browser vertically, the height is now being inherited from the size of the window, all the way down to the children.